# What's an example of a robot that has both a URDF and DH parameters available?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a robot model that has both a URDF, as well as DH parameters available. I was wondering if anyone can make any suggestions? Google is failing me...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248712/what%27s-an-example-of-a-robot-that-has-both-a-urdf-and-dh-parameters-available?/) by [HD7199b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28604/hd7199b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS-Industrial's UR series of xacros? See [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/indigo-devel/ur_description/urdf/ur5.urdf.xacro#L25-L42) for the UR5 fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HD7199b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28604/hd7199b/) on 2016-11-23**:
Thanks, I came across that one earlier but for some reason didn't see the meshes it contained (which I also require)